# Spark Scala : Fetch distinct text values within each cell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to scala and I have been having trouble fetching distinct text values from each cell of a row. My dataframe looks somewhat like this below. My intent is to eliminate duplicate skills for each candidate id.

| candidate_id | skills | join_date | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1789s3 | java; c++ ; java | 2012-09-22 | Mumbai |
| agduch23 | ppt ; ppt ; miner | 2018-02-02 | Banglore |
| sgdtev | office 365; | 2019-03-10 | Noida |

My final resultant dataframe should look somewhat like this -

| candidate_id | skills | join_date | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1789s3 | java; c++ | 2012-09-22 | Mumbai |
| agduch23 | ppt; miner | 2018-02-02 | Banglore |
| sgdtev | office 365; | 2019-03-10 | Noida |

I use the following command in SQL to do this.

```sql
string_agg(ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY((select distinct skill from unnest(split(skills_agg, '; ')) as skill)), '; ')) as skills_distinct
```

Is there a way I can do this in scala without using sql.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spark 3.0 and greater, you can remove duplicate by splitting your string to an array with `split`, then use function `array_distinct` to remove duplicates and finally rebuild string with `concat_ws`, as follow:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_distinct, col, concat_ws, split}

dataframe.withColumn("skills", concat_ws("; ", array_distinct(split(col("skills"), "; ")))
```

You can find all the functions you can use in [Scala API functions' Scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html)